# Modelling a relationship which has multiple one-to-many parents

Tags: postgresql, database-design, erd

I am attempting to model a relationship which could have two parents, one of them being optional, and the other being mandatory. The design should have the following rules,

- A `House` **must** exist as the top level parent
- A `Bedroom` **must** have a house as a parent
- A `House` can have many `Bedroom`s
- A `House` can have many `Photo`s of the house
- A `Photo` could also optionally be linked to a `Bedroom`, i.e. it is a photo of a bedroom in a house
- A `User` should only be able to access a `House` and any child (`Bedroom` and `Photo` resources) that are owned by them (through the `UserID` field in `House` table)

My current design looks like this:

```
    +---------+         +-----------+
    | House   |         | Bedroom   |
    +---------+         +-----------+
+---> HouseID <---+     | BedroomID <----+
|   | UserID  |   +-----+ HouseID   |    |
|   | ...     |         | ...       |    |
|   +---------+         +-----------+    |
|                                        |
|                                        |
|           +-----------+                |
|           | Photo     |                |
|           +-----------+                |
|           | PhotoID   |                |
+-----------+ HouseID   |   OPTIONAL     |
            | BedroomID +----------------+
            | ...       |
            +-----------+
```

I currently enforce that a `Photo` **must** be linked to a `House` through the FK, so I can perform a `JOIN` to get the original `UserID`, as I know this key will already exist, but it feels like this is not the right way to go about it.

I ideally want to return `Photo`s that are **only** linked to the `House` when querying data about the `House`, and then only `Photo`s linked to a `Bedroom` when querying data about a `Bedroom`. I know this is quite easy to do via `JOIN`s, but it makes me question whether this is the right design, as it seems to be more "working around the design" than fixing the root problem.

Would it be more useful to use mapping tables here? Or any further ideas on how to improve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your table design is good and normalized.

One thing that is not guaranteed yet is that if a `photo` references a `bedroom`, that `bedroom` should belong to the same `house` as the `photo`.

You could get that with an additional `UNIQUE` constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE bedroom
   ADD UNIQUE (houseid, bedroomid);
```

Then the foreign key constraint could be defined as:

```
ALTER TABLE photo
   ADD FOREIGN KEY (houseid, bedroomid) REFERENCES bedroom (houseid, bedroomid);
```

An extra index is not nice from a performance angle, but you want an index on the `houseid` column of `bedroom` anyway because of the foreign key, so an additional column shouldn't hurt.